# Bogus "This web site needs a different Google Maps API key" with STATIC image map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Starting from recently, any request I try to get a static image from the Google Static Map API gets this text response:

> This web site needs a different Google Maps API key

According to documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits

> Note that the use of a key is not required, though it is recommended. Examples in this document do not include the key parameter so that they will work for all users who cut-and-paste the code.

Has this changed and did they forget to document it? There's a warning at the doc page that says the usage limits have changed (though then the usage limit that are claimed are the same as before!!) but it doesn't say that the use of an API key has become required.

If I had hit the usage limit, which I certainly haven't, then I would (or should) get a different response, as I experienced in the past.

The exact same requests used to work until recently.

Can anybody clarify?

Example request:
http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=45.54309129999999,-73.62077841957398&zoom=16&size=480x360&maptype=mobile&markers=45.54309129999999,-73.62077841957398&sensor=false

Answer (score 1):

I appears you are using an old URL for V1 (whose deprecation period has ended), for V2 it has to be:

[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=45.54309129999999,-73.62077841957398&zoom=16&size=480x360&maptype=hybrid&markers=45.54309129999999,-73.62077841957398&sensor=false&mobile=true`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=45.54309129999999,-73.62077841957398&zoom=16&size=480x360&maptype=hybrid&markers=45.54309129999999,-73.62077841957398&sensor=false&mobile=true)